# String Manipulation in Powershell

Tags: string, powershell

PS1 script:

```
$search = New-Object DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher([ADSI]"")
$search.filter = "(servicePrincipalName=*)"

## You can use this to filter for OU's:
## $results = $search.Findall() | ?{ $_.path -like '*OU=whatever,DC=whatever,DC=whatever*' }
$results = $search.Findall()

foreach( $result in $results ) {
    $userEntry = $result.GetDirectoryEntry()
    Write-host "Object Name =   "   $userEntry.name -backgroundcolor "yellow" -foregroundcolor "black"
    Write-host "DN  =   "   $userEntry.distinguishedName
    Write-host "Object Cat. =   " $userEntry.objectCategory
    Write-host "servicePrincipalNames"

    $i=1
    foreach( $SPN in $userEntry.servicePrincipalName ) {
        Write-host "SPN ${i} =$SPN"
        $i+=1
        $string = $SPN
        $sep = "/"
        $option = [System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries
        $address = $string.Split($sep)
        Write-Host "ADDRESS = $address"
        $ip = nslookup $address
        Write-Host "$ip"
    }
    Write-host ""

}
```

My problem arises here:

```
Write-host "SPN ${i} =$SPN"
            $i+=1
            $string = $SPN
            $sep = "/"
            $option = [System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries
            $address = $string.Split($sep)
            Write-Host "ADDRESS = $address"
            $ip = nslookup $address
            Write-Host "$ip"
```

$SPN will return the full service prinicipal name, for example HOST/DC01.com, and I want to manipulate that to remove all "/" and everything to the left of them. In the case above $address should equal DC01.com. Currently it returns "HOST DC01.com".

Comment: What's wrong with `($SPN -split "/")[-1]`?

Comment: Thanks! This worked